# Ability to share .pdf using email not working in Preview

Tags: macos, preview, sharing

Preview has the ability to "share" documents by mailing them. When I select this feature, nothing happens. I don't get an error  message.

Is there a fix for this? 
I've already tried removing com.apple.Preview from containers and group containers, but this did not work.

I'm running OS-X 10.10.2 on a late 2013 MBPr. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your icon on Mail would seem to appear that Google Chrome is set to be your mail client.

It works fine if Apple Mail is set as default mailer.

I can't even persuade Chrome to be accepted as a mailer from [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). I'd certainly be tempted to try switching the default to something else.